# How to configure checkbox in alert controller and return value in Ionic 4?

Tags: checkbox, ionic4

I have a button that logs an event. When the button is clicked it automatically picks the chosen date from a calendar. after this the user would have to register two boolean attributes. I don't know how to do this efficiently. Can someone help me?

```
async cadastrarPresenca() {
let ida: boolean;
let volta: boolean;


const alert = await this.alertController.create({
  header: 'Confirmar ida e/ou volta',
  inputs: [
    {
      name: 'Ida',
      type: 'checkbox',
      label: 'Ida',
      value: ida,
    },
    {
      name: 'Volta',
      type: 'checkbox',
      label: 'Volta',
      value: volta
    }],
  buttons: [
    {
      text: 'Cancel',
      role: 'cancel',
      cssClass: 'secondary',
      handler: () => {
        console.log('Confirm Cancel');
      }
    }, {
      text: 'Ok',
      handler: () => {
        let start = this.dataSelecionada;
        let end = this.dataSelecionada;
        end.setMinutes(end.getMinutes() + 60);
        let presenca = {
          title: 'Event #' + start.getMinutes(),
          startTime: start,
          endTime: end,
          allDay: false,
          ida: ida,
          volta: volta
        };
        this.firestore.collection('aluno').doc(this.authService.getUsuario().uid).collection('presenca').add(presenca);
      }
    }
  ]
});

await alert.present();
```

Comment: hey Marco, sorry it’s super unclear as to what you are trying to do:( can you provide details of exact user experience?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to update your ok handler so that the data is passed in and then you can use it:

```
async cadastrarPresenca() {
let ida: boolean;
let volta: boolean;


const alert = await this.alertController.create({
  header: 'Confirmar ida e/ou volta',
  inputs: [
    {
      name: 'Ida',
      type: 'checkbox',
      label: 'Ida',
      value: ida,
    },
    {
      name: 'Volta',
      type: 'checkbox',
      label: 'Volta',
      value: volta
    }],
  buttons: [
    {
      text: 'Cancel',
      role: 'cancel',
      cssClass: 'secondary',
      handler: () => {
        console.log('Confirm Cancel');
      }
    }, {
      text: 'Ok',

   // NEW CODE HERE
      handler: (inputData) => {
        console.log(inputData);
        console.log(inputData["Volta"].checked);
   // END OF NEW CODE HERE

        let start = this.dataSelecionada;
        let end = this.dataSelecionada;
        end.setMinutes(end.getMinutes() + 60);
        let presenca = {
          title: 'Event #' + start.getMinutes(),
          startTime: start,
          endTime: end,
          allDay: false,
          ida: ida,
          volta: volta
        };
        this.firestore.collection('aluno').doc(this.authService.getUsuario().uid).collection('presenca').add(presenca);
      }
    }
  ]
});

await alert.present();
```

So the new code is all that I've changed from your snippet:

```
   // NEW CODE HERE
      handler: (inputData) => {
        console.log(inputData);
        console.log(inputData["Volta"].checked);
   // END OF NEW CODE HERE
```

You can [look at the code that Ionic is built on](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/50b0c6f15d7c6c351cd307b80f377869e3fa4e8d/core/src/components/alert/alert-interface.ts#L22) for reference to see what options should be available, or just check out the first `console.log` I added.